# Facebook FB.login works in Safari, but not mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile-safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

The following FB.Login function works fine in desktop Chrome, FF, and Safari.
But in mobile Safari (tested on an iPhone 4S), it hangs and does not return to the FB.login callback. I can also see this in the console when I use Safari and set the User Agent to "Safari iOS 4.3.3 - iPhone".

Is it because mobile Safari blocks popups? (FB.login triggers a popup dialog).

How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
function Login(returnLink) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
                    if(response.status === 'connected') {
                        console.log('User is now FB logged in.');
                        // now log them into my site
                        encodedReturnLink = encodeURIComponent(returnLink);
                        window.location = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/login?returnUrl=" + encodedReturnLink;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('User did not fully authorize after clicking FB login button.');
                    }
                },
                {scope : 'email, publish_actions, publish_stream'}
        );
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this immediately after user interaction (click/tap/submit) or from some delayed code?

Comment: Running into the same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to run `FB.Login` automatically on page load inside `window.fbAsyncInit` and it wasn't working in Safari on iOS. It turns out Safari was blocking the popup window triggered by the FB.Login call. Safari and Chrome on the desktop worked fine (allowed the popup).

I found the only way to work-around this was to trigger the FB.Login call in response to user interaction (eg. Tap or Click). This worked for me:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="fbLogin">Login with Facebook</a>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$('#fbLogin').click(function(){
    FB.login(function(response){
        // Do something...
    });
});
```

Tested on Safari (iOS 8.0).

Comment: +1 for giving correct solution. It removed my headache. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Safari seems pretty sensitive to blocking pop ups. If you delay at all (even by waiting a tiny amount for other callbacks) it seems to trigger the block.

Comment: @wireblue is this still the only way to trigger the login in current versions?

Comment: @gapvision, I have not tested this recently so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not a matter of blocking popups.  Though I have seen a scenario in which the login works when called directly, but not when the result of an ajax callback.

Comment: well, but this is indeed a matter of blocking popups, as it is obviously blocked when called as callback and not when called directly?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check Mobile Site URL in your Facebook app settings.